# How to check Space between Two images

Tags: python, perl, selenium-rc

Consider there are two images in a webpage.

I want know if they have any space rendered between them.

I'm using selenium tool and python language.

Answer could be in any language.

Answer (score 1):

you can look up the position and size of each image quickly with javascript (I'm using jquery)

```
$('#image-one').width

                height

                x

                y
```

$('#image-two')...same thing

Just see if the x of one is right next to the x+width of the other.  Repeat for Y.

edit: there may be some issues with parents that have relative positioning.  The code here is probably more bulletproof than just using x and y:

http://blog.firetree.net/2005/07/04/javascript-find-position/

Comment: you mean x of one =x+width of other right? and similar for y?

Comment: When I was playing with it, it was just .x and .y I'm not sure if that is straight JavaScript or jury, but it was working.  Also look at the link in my answer for a better way to determine x and y

Comment: I got these inbuilt functions are these gonna help. info------>get_element_position_left                                   get_element_position_top                                             get_element_width      and    get_element_height